# Integrating the Login and Comments Plugins

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-comments, facebook-login

I'm trying to integrate both the Facebook **login button** and the **comments plugin** on my page.

I have them working separately, and when someone logs in via the login button, the comments plugin responds (and logs the user in), but my issue is the other way around; **when someone logs in to post a comment via the comments plugin, there is no event to pass to the login button from the comments plugin.**

Is there any way around this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register to a FB javascript event on comment, or better yet to login. The login event should be triggered when the user logs in from a like or comment action:

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId   : 'xxxx',
                    status  : true, // check login status
                    cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                    xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
                }); 
   FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() { 

                      /*create a reload in wich you login the user, because now you have the cookie. Or via ajax */
             });
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I already have this code in place, but it only works for when a user logs in using the login button. You are saying that the comments plugin should also fire the auth.login?

Comment: that's what I understood from the docs : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/. I used it on Like action an worked..I presumed the login via comments plugin is the same..

Comment: Anyway, if it doesn you should do something like, check for comment.create event and in it check the login status : FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function() { 

                     
             });

Comment: status check : FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                  if (response.status === 'connected') {}}

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but the problem is is that the user could log in via the comments, and then decide not to comment, then they would have to still log in via the login button.

Comment: But does that event trigger? the comment.create event? maybe there really is a localhost problem. Anyway, I don;t see way you want to catch this on the fly. Once is logged in from whatever fb plugin after refresh you can detect that and start server side (app) login

Comment: The comment create event does indeed trigger, as does the other comment one (delete? edit?). 
What do you mean by 'after refresh'?
I'm going to put it on my server tonight and see what happens.

Comment: Just tried it on my live webserver and no cigar either. I'm thinking maybe the comments plugin doesn't send login events.